# Magento Connect: Unable to upload new release error message

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

Today I finished my plug-in and I would like to add it to the Magento Connect store by choosing for "Add Extension" but when I do that I get the following errormessage:

> An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect 1.0: Unable to upload new release e102c963387e144a2eb6768b2ebc51ec-0.1.0.tgz
>   An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect 2.0: Channels names doesn't match 'Plesents_Plugin' and 'community'

I've followed the official [pdf tutorial file](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf) for adding the extension to the Magento Connect store. I'm packaging for Magento 1.7 only.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes I've followed the official .pdf file for adding the extention to the Magento Connect store [link](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf)[/link] I'm packaging for Magento 1.7 only.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the same pdf shortly and had no problems.

From the file:

```
Extension Key:
The extension key must be the exact same name you used during the packaging process.
```

To check if the names match have a look in the `var/connect/package.xml` of your module. Theres a node `name`. Compare it to value you entered when uploading the package.

Comment: Is this the same key that I can find in the URL on the backend of Magento? My plug-in is 90% backend based and on all pages from my plug-in in the backend there is an key in the URL, I've used that one. ex: https://magentostore.example/index.php/admin/Plugin/index/key/fea42452e38c47de5bc5a2dd57537be0/

Comment: Its the value you entered in the name field when creating your package. It has nothing to do with url keys.

Comment: can I find it back in the source of the plug-in .tgz file?

Comment: There should be a xml file where all values you entered in creation process are stored. Search for a tag `name`.